# Why I cannot reach non-persistent listeners count from my UnityEvent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, listener, hook

I need to know how many non-persistent listeners were added to a UnityEvent.

It seems that there is no methods giving me this number in UnityEvent class. I can only get the persistent listeners count (the ones added from editor or with UnityEvent.AddPersistentListener() ). 
The only solution I have figured out is to create a child class and override the function with a count of registrations.

Here is a short code showing the problem :

```
    private UnityEvent myEvent;

    private void MyFunctionToHook()
    {
        // func logic
    }

    private void MyInitialisation()
    {
        myEvent.AddListener(MyFunctionToHook);
        myEvent.AddListener(MyFunctionToHook);
        myEvent.AddListener(MyFunctionToHook);

        // here, I need to know how much hooks were added.
        // ??
    }
```

1) Do you have any ideas of how I can manage to track this information natively?

2) Am I doing this right ? Is it wrong wanting to know this information ?

It seems weird to not have access to this info, because it could be useful in unit-tests / warnings..etc

Thanks for your time.

Here is the unityEvent documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html

[EDIT]
the only solution I have found so far is the following :

```
    public class TrackingUnityEvent<T0> : UnityEvent<T0>
{
    private int nonPersistentListenersCount;

    public int GetNonPersistentEventCount()
    {
        return nonPersistentListenersCount;
    }

    public void AddNonPersistantListener(UnityAction<T0> call)
    {
        AddListener(call);
        nonPersistentListenersCount++;
    }

    public void RemoveNonPersistantListener(UnityAction<T0> call)
    {
        RemoveListener(call);
        nonPersistentListenersCount--;
    }
}
```

This way is gross because you can't tell if "RemoveListener()" and "AddListener()" are successfull as they are void.

Comment: It would make sense to post example of your non-persistent listeners  code and how you can currently get the count of persistent listeners. That will help people figure out an answer if there is one.

Comment: this discussion on C# events dovetails with the seemingly missing-functionality in UnityEvents. ie, no iterating or counting the listeners. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/536b810f-c5f0-44e9-be24-f7b55d424549/iterating-through-event-handlers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap the event inside another class without inheritance, so that you can count the listener? You can also add more code to the event...

```cs
public class MySpecialEvent {
    private UnityEvent event;
    public EventCount { get; private set; }

    public void AddListener(UnityAction call) {
        event.AddListener(call);
        EventCount++;
    }

    public void RemoveListener(UnityAction call) {
        event.RemoveListener(call);
        EventCount--;
    }
}
```